# How to access attributes from inside a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, models

I have a model named item that has a column named price. I assumed that price would be stored as an instance variable inside item but the method

```
def price
  @price
end
```

Returns nothing. So my question is how can I access and override the value price pulled from the database from inside my model.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You use according to the [Rails guides](https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide#read-attribute)

```
def price
  self[:price]
end
```